# Ocorreu um erro TypeError: lista.map is not a function

Tags: angular

Recebo o erro descrito no titulo nesta situação:

```
carregarCategorias() {
    this.itemService.listarCategorias().then(lista => {
      this.categorias = lista.map(categoria => ({ label: categoria.descricao, value: categoria.id }));
    })
    .catch(erro => this.errorHandler.handle(erro));
  }
```

Alguem tem alguma dica ?

Comment: Significa que `lista` não é um `array`. Você pode facilmente confirmar o que é fazendo `console.log(typeof lista, lista)` dentro da *promise*

Comment: O método da busca  utilizado no service é este  :

listarCategorias(): Promise<Categoria[]> {
return this.http.get<Categoria[]>(this.categoriasUrl).toPromise();
} o retorno ai não é um array ?

Comment: Valeu pela dica,  realmente o retorno era um Page<> e não um list por isso o map não funcionar.  Vlw